# Is GRUB needed after converting an earlier dual boot system to only ubuntu system?

Tags: grub2, dual-boot

Well as the question says,

I earlier had a dual boot system with windows and ubuntu.Now I have deleted windows.

So do i really need GRUB now? coz actually grub does not show up but neither is Ubuntu directly booted like it would in an "always only ubuntu system"

In an "always only ubuntu system",the splash screen directly comes up.

But what I see before Ubuntu starts is a countdowsn from 5,and a message displaying "press esc to enter into menu"

Then what is displayed is something like-

"booting from (0,hd7)..." and then ubuntu starts...

So can I or do I need to remove grub so that ubuntu boots like it is an "always only ubuntu system"??

Thankyou.

Answer (score 5):

- GRUB is the bootloader and is always needed
- To hide GRUB and boot to the splash screen, Please  add/edit these lines in `/etc/default/grub`:

  ```
  GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
  GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
  ```
- Save, and then run `sudo update-grub`; reboot

Comment: Well its not working!  still those msgs I have mentioned do come up!

Answer (score 2):

The way I like to tweak grub is by using [Grub Customizer](https://launchpad.net/~danielrichter2007/+archive/grub-customizer) a nice little GUI app.

> Grub Customizer is a graphical interface to configure the grub2/burg settings with focus on the individual list order - without losing the dynamical behavior of grub.

If you want to give it a try add the following PPA to your sources list by opening up your **Ubuntu Software Centre** and then clicking **Edit/Software Sources** from the top menu. Then select the **Other Software** tab then down the bottom click **Add** and then if your Ubuntu version is Precise paste the first link from below lastly click **Add Source** repeat with the second link.

*Note: To find PPAs for other verions try the link at the end of this answer*

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/danielrichter2007/grub-customizer/ubuntu precise main 

deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/danielrichter2007/grub-customizer/ubuntu precise main
```

Now open up your terminal and type the following.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

When it finishes open it up and click **Preferences** then on the **General** tab make sure the options under visibility are unchecked. *Figure 1*

[image: General Tab]

Then select the **Advanced** tab and make sure your setting are the same as Figure 2

[image]

Then save and reboot to see the changes! I hope that helps.

**References**

[Grub Customizer](https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. GRUB makes your Ubuntu boot, no matter how many operating systems are installed. A bootloader is always required for an operating system to function.

Comment: okay...then how do I make the bootloader not show anything and just boot to the splash screen? and as far as i know something like "show grub when shoft is pressded or else keep it hidden" does exist...so how do I do it?

Comment: See izx's answer.